# How can I view the cache-hit ratio for a single column-family in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

I've enabled row-caching in for one of my column-families in Cassandra and I'l like to view the cache-hit ratio?

I can see the cache-hit ration metric in Cassandra's OspCenter but it seems to show me the information for the entire cluster? Is there a way I could get this metric?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of version 1.2, the key cache and row cache are global to make better use of the off-heap functionality. Unfortunately, this means those stats are no longer available on the column family level.

If you only have it enabled for one column family, you should be able to see what you need via the global stats per-node on the cassandra-level options (I think that's what they are called in OpsCenter, have not looked in a while) when you go to 'Add a Graph.'

These stats are available from the command line via `nodetool info` (last 2 lines of output).